# ANDROID Swipe UI

Tags: android, swipe

I've set up a view in which I can swipe between various views, each using the same fragment. I've seen in many other apps that a row of dots is often used to indicate which of several views/fragments you're currently at.

What kind of object do I use to do that? Is there a predefined one, or do I have to construct it out of some other set of objects?

Answer (score 2):

There is an open source library called viewpagerindicator http://viewpagerindicator.com